# Problem with setting up dynamic list of subforms with flask, wtforms and jinja2

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I'm fairly new to the Python world (planing to make a switch and leave the CurlyBracesCamelCaseWorld) and I'm working on the simple app go get exp in the whole initial stack (database, server, handling html pages & assets, etc).

So far so good, the pace of the development never ceases to amaze me and the amount of resources is hearth worming.

But I've encounter the problem that I just can't get past by.

What I try to do now:

- Have a main wtform with a static set of fields
- Add dynamically generated list of sub-forms - prepopulated with values and with custom labels

In my apps scenario user will be able to specify the list of questions to answer - so there will be a form with common details + the dynamic list, that I can use to save the data to the database on submit.

I have a whole list of issues here

1) The main problem is that I can't read the subforms data in the .validate() when I submit the form

2) The other thing is that I can't force the labels to show the custom values That I want to set dynamically

3) I need to do more reading on handling csfr in subforms and how to work around that as well

4) And the last one - how do I validate the subforms - for required fields, length, etc

1 & 2 is my main concern now and I have a feeling that the issues have the same root-cause
My gut feeling tells me that the broken element id is meaningful ('content' for each subform string field, instead of indexed 'entries-0-content' - that I see on submit)

I wasn't able to find the full example how to do that and I'm struggling to connect the pieces I collected. I prepared the simple code, both python & jinja2 template, ready to run, to demonstrate the problems. I'll gladly post the full working code after I figure it out as I'd kill to find just that..

So, the server ->

```py
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, FieldList, FormField, SubmitField, HiddenField, Label
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='flaskblog/templates')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET_KEY-SECRET_KEY-SECRET_KEY'


# subforms
class SubForm(FlaskForm):
    # how to handle hidden id that I can use to properly commit that on submit?
    # entry_type_id = HiddenField()

    # validators for subforms don't work, but that's something I'll try to address later
    content = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])

    # I use custom __init__ set custom label for the field - or rather I try, as it doesn't work..
    def __init__(self, custom_label=None, *args, **kwargs):
        # not sure if safe - even just for the subform! #
        # Without that, I get 'TypeError: argument of type 'CSRFTokenField' is not iterable' on main_form.validate_on_submit()
        kwargs['csrf_enabled'] = False
        FlaskForm.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        if custom_label is not None:
            self.content.label = Label(self.content.id, custom_label)
            print(f'INIT // id: [{self.content.id}] // content.data: [{self.content.data}] // label: [{self.content.label.text}]')


# main forms
class MainForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title')
    entries = FieldList(FormField(SubForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Post')


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_route():
    # the main form
    main_form = MainForm(title='title')

    # sub forms, created before validate_on_submit()
    sub_form_1 = SubForm(content='Default answer 1', custom_label='Question 1')
    sub_form_2 = SubForm(content='Default answer 2', custom_label='Question 2')

    main_form.entries.append_entry(sub_form_1)
    main_form.entries.append_entry(sub_form_2)

    if main_form.validate_on_submit():
        for entry in main_form.entries.entries:
            print(f'LOOP // id: [{entry.content.id}] // content.data: [{entry.content.data}] // label: [{entry.content.label.text}]')

        return redirect(url_for('test_route'))

    print(f'INSTANCE_1 // id: [{sub_form_1.content.id}] // content.data: [{sub_form_1.content.data}] // label: [{sub_form_1.content.label.text}]')
    print(f'INSTANCE_2 // id: [{sub_form_2.content.id}] // content.data: [{sub_form_2.content.data}] // label: [{sub_form_2.content.label.text}]')

    return render_template('test_form.html', title='Test Form', main_form=main_form, legend='Test Form')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And the html template ->

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <title> Confused -.-' </title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="content-section">

    <form action="" method="post">
        {{ main_form.hidden_tag() }}
        {{ main_form.title.label(class="form-control-label") }}: {{ main_form.title(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}

        {% for entry_line in main_form.entries %}
            <div class="form-group">
                {{ entry_line.content.label(class="form-control-label") }}
                {{ entry_line.content.data(class="form-control form-control-lg") }}
            </div>
        {% endfor %}

        {# For the main form I use main_form.title(), main_form.submit(), etc - without .data(). #}
        {# If I try to do main_form.title.data() I get the ex that I can't call on 'str' #}

        {# But, for entry_lines, if I don't add .data() and just use entry_line.content()  #}
        {# I can see the input field, but it's prepopulated with HTML for that input instead of the value (that I see in that html) #}

        <div class="form-group">
            {{ main_form.submit(class="btn btn-outline-info") }}
        </div>
    </form>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

Debug on GET:

```
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 1] // label: [Question 1]
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 2] // label: [Question 2]
INSTANCE_1 // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 1] // label: [Question 1]
INSTANCE_2 // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 2] // label: [Question 2]
```

Debug on POST:

```
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [my ans 1] // label: [Question 1]
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [my ans 1] // label: [Question 2]
LOOP // id: [entries-0-content] // content.data: [<input id="content" name="content" type="text" value="my ans 1">] // label: [Content]
LOOP // id: [entries-1-content] // content.data: [<input id="content" name="content" type="text" value="my ans 1">] // label: [Content]
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 1] // label: [Question 1]
INIT // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 2] // label: [Question 2]
INSTANCE_1 // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 1] // label: [Question 1]
INSTANCE_2 // id: [content] // content.data: [Default answer 2] // label: [Question 2]
```

There is clearly some issue with ids (2x content vs entries-0-content) & I get the first result twice.. (value="my ans 1")

I'd love to be able to generate the full form list based on the list of questions (I just use a static 2 here), set the custom labels per subform and then get the data in the server, so I can do the rest of the job inn there.

I can fight with validation and csfr myself after that, but having the working scaffolding seems like a valid first step. I've spend a lot of time poking around but I feel like I'm running in circle now.

And ofc - if you think that my assumptions on how to achieve what I want to achieve are wrong and I should use  to do that - let me know. I want to write the right thing, not just something that works.

Pastebin links, if you prefer

- [app.py](https://pastebin.com/Ye7VYede)
- [test_form.html](https://pastebin.com/RBsb2Z2D)
- [result HTML page](https://pastebin.com/Brm5mQgS)

## EDIT - working code

Thanks to @Nick K9!

```
from flask import Flask, redirect, url_for, render_template, request
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, FieldList, FormField, SubmitField, HiddenField, Label
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__, template_folder='flaskblog/templates')
app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'SECRET_KEY-SECRET_KEY-SECRET_KEY'

subform_datasource = {
    0: {'question': 'Question 1', 'answare': 'Answare 1'},
    1: {'question': 'Question 2', 'answare': 'Answare 2'}
}


# subforms
class SubForm(FlaskForm):
    entry_type_id = HiddenField()
    content = StringField(validators=[DataRequired()])


# main forms
class MainForm(FlaskForm):
    title = StringField('title')
    entries = FieldList(FormField(SubForm))
    submit = SubmitField('Post')


@app.route("/test", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def test_route():
    main_form = MainForm()
    if main_form.validate_on_submit():
        for entry in main_form.entries.entries:
            entry_message = (
                f'POST // wtform id: [{entry.content.id}] '
                f' //  entry_type_id id: [{entry.entry_type_id.data}]'
                f' //  content.data: [{entry.content.data}]'
                f' //  label: [{entry.content.label.text}]'
            )
            print(str(entry_message))

        return redirect(url_for('test_route'))
    elif request.method == 'GET':
        # You can indeed set the default values, but you need to pass the dict, not the SubForm instance!
        for key, subform in subform_datasource.items():
            main_form.entries.append_entry({'content': subform['answare'], 'entry_type_id': key})

    # Moved out from the constructor - on subform failed validation labels reset to the default value 'Content'
    # I guess that matching what was send to the form does not cast back the labels but creates the fresh instances with just the value
    # What, of course, makes sense - it's an edge case, no point in affecting performance for everyone
    for entry in main_form.entries.entries:
        entry.content.label.text = subform_datasource[entry.entry_type_id.data]['question']

    return render_template('test_form.html', title='Test Form', main_form=main_form, legend='Test Form')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

2 links that also helped me

- [an actual example I was looking for](https://gist.github.com/doobeh/5d0f965502b86fee80fe)
- [a question from the same realm](https://www.reddit.com/r/flask/comments/3nn460/af_populate_fieldlistformfield/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have the right idea, but there are a few issues with what you've done:

1. You shouldn't explicitly create the SubForm instances. Pass a dictionary to `append_entry()` to populate the fields in the subform. (**Edit:** Took out incorrect information about passing form instances to `append_entry()`. It needs to be a dictionary object.)
2. You should call `append_entry()` **after** the `validate_on_submit()` block, not before. When the POST request comes back with your form, it will already have sufficient subforms created. You did that when the page was built. You just need to read all the form contents and pull out/save your data before the redirect.
3. You mentioned missing data and uncalled validation. I have a hunch that at present you're overwriting the form data before the validation method is called. So this problem may resolve itself.
4. You mentioned CSRF. You need to include `{{ entry_line.hidden_tag() }}` inside the subform `for` loop. That should be all you need to get CSRF working with the subform.

Try that and see if your form starts working.

Comment: Ok, I got this! Thanks to @nick-k9's comment I was able to push that past the setback and I can share the working solution, for future travelers.
Nick, especially thank you for pointing out to take a closer look at `append_entry()`! I figured out how to populate the sub-form with initial data - you just need to pass the `dict` not the object instance!

Comment: That's great, glad you got this working. The [`append_entry` code](https://github.com/wtforms/wtforms/blob/277a437db29e36db3e211f47c93675eb544d6443/src/wtforms/fields/core.py#L1123) seems pretty clear that it's expecting an object, not a dictionary: "Entries added in this way will *not* receive formdata however, and can only receive object data." The documentation could be MUCH clearer on this point.

Comment: Yes, I've seen that line and I think that the dict is what they mean by 'object data'.. But true, it could be way more informative and clear than now.
Anyway - thank you very much for pointing me out in the right direction!

Comment: Well, look at that. I think I was misreading the code. Seems `data` is a dictionary of objects understood by each field, so I guess `formdata` is form instances. Exactly the opposite of what I was expecting! And yet there are SO many bits of github code where people are passing form instances to `append_entry()`. Maybe it changed at some point. Thanks for learnin' me some new WTForms stuff.